how can I write to multiple registers on a microcontroller?
I'm using modbus poll to write to multiple registers on a microcontroller using USB to rs232 cable.
Now I want to do the same thing using CMD or a script file, but I don't know how. I am a beginner at this so I don't even know where to look for.
I tried the modbus cli repo from favalex but I wasn't able to connect to my microcontroller (I didn't know how)
any help on this matter would be great
I tried pymodbus like @Guillius said and this is my code:
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
client = ModbusSerialClient(method="rtu",port="com14",baudrate=9600,bytesize=8,parity="N",stopbits=1)
client.connect()

result of client.connect is true
res = client.read_holding_registers(address=0x00,count=1,unit=1)

res value is <pymodbus.pdu.ExceptionResponse at 0x4ecfff0> which is an error.
I want to get the value of the register by
res.registers

but I don't know what to do

is modbus poll an application?
Are you for example looking for a Python library so you can make a python script doing that? Which OS is your computer?

@Guillius yes modbus poll is an application and yes I am looking for a Python library or any other way to do this

my os is windows

"I am looking for a Python library" requests for libraries are off topic here - pick a library and focus your question on that. Ref the error you are getting, we will need the details (e.g. what micro-controller); check for errors as shown in this example. Note that connect opens the serial port but does not actually communicate with the device (so the fact this succeeds does not mean settings like Baud rate are necessarily correct).

I used this before, and I checked: should work on both Windows and Linux systems.
https://pypi.org/project/pymodbus/

I tried the library but I wasn't successful this is my code:
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
Import modbus.framer as framer
client = ModbusSerialClient("com14",framer=Framer,baudrate=9600,bytesize=8,parity="N",stopbits=1)
I get invalid framer method requested
